# Does Logstash truncate plugin add tags only if message was really truncated?

Tags: logstash

According to the [documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-truncate.html#plugins-filters-truncate-add_tag), the `truncate` fliter plugin for Logstash can add tags "if the filter is successful":

> add_tag 
>   Value type is array 
>   Default value is [] 
>   If this filter is
>   successful, add arbitrary tags to the event. Tags can be dynamic and
>   include parts of the event using the %{field} syntax.

Does this mean the tags are added if the fields were truncated only, or everytime the filter is applied even if the fields were not truncated? I'd like the first behavior.

Comment: The `add_tag` option is part of the options common to all filters, which behave in the same way for all filters, so I'd say it's every time the filter is applied.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did a quick test.

Using this configuration:

```
input {
  stdin {}
}

filter {
    truncate{
        length_bytes => 10
        add_tag => ["tag"]          
    }       
}

output {
  stdout {
    codec => json
  }
}
```

Input: `test` This input is short enough not to get cut by the `truncate` filter.

Output:

```
{"tags":["tag"],"host":"notTellingYou","@timestamp":"someTime","message":"test\r","@version":"1"}
```

Input: `01234567890123456789` This input will get cut by the `truncate` filter

Output:

```
{"tags":["tag"],"host":"notTellingYou","@timestamp":"someTime","message":"0123456789","@version":"1"}
```

The tag is always applied, even if no fields were truncated.